# Can't get servlet to print to text file

Tags: java, servlets

this is my code so far, want to get it to print without local path but it only prints when I write the path from

```
C:\Users\Javier\Documents\NetBeansProjects\HW5JavierSantana\web\WEB-INF\inputs.txt
```

can't seem to get it to work any other way. Any and all help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    Writer writer = null;

    String usersLogin = request.getParameter("name");
    String usersTitle = request.getParameter("title");
    String usersName = request.getParameter("username");
    String usersSupervisor = request.getParameter("supervisor");
    String usersPassword = request.getParameter("password");

    response.setContentType("text/plain");

    String file = this.getServletContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF/inputs.txt");
    System.out.println(file);//<-- prints correct/expected path            
    try{
        writer = new BufferedWriter(new PrintWriter(file));
        writer.write("Employee Info ");
        writer.write(" | UserName: " + usersLogin +
        " | Title: " + usersTitle +
        " | Name: " + usersName +
        " | Supervisor: " + usersSupervisor + 
        " | Password: " + usersPassword);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        writer.close();
    }

    String url = "/WEB-INF/registered.jsp";
    getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(url).forward(request, response);

}
```

Log output is:

```
...
INFO: Reloading Context with name [/HW5JavierSantana] has started Apr 21, 2015 7:33:19 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload INFO: Reloading Context with name [/HW5JavierSantana] is completed
C:\Users\Javier\Documents\NetBeansProjects\HW5JavierSantana\build\web\WEB-INF\in‌​puts.txt
```

Comment: Can you verify, whether `file=="C:\Users\Javier\Documents\NetBeansProjects\HW5JavierSantana\web\WEB-INF\inputs.txt"` (or maybe a different location) ?

Comment: how would i go about checking for that?

Comment: ..I feared you would ask about that! :-) You run in netbeans!? ..you know/watch the "console"!? ..add a `System.out.println(file);` between initialization (of `file`) and `try`. ....then watch the console (on execution).

Comment: Will do, thank you. I'll let you know what comes up

Comment: it does give the correct path

Comment: ..and still "doesnt print to inputs.txt"!? ..and no "irregularities" (error messages/stack traces) in your console?

Comment: none my log shows 

INFO: Reloading Context with name [/HW5JavierSantana] has started
Apr 21, 2015 7:33:19 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
INFO: Reloading Context with name [/HW5JavierSantana] is completed
C:\Users\Javier\Documents\NetBeansProjects\HW5JavierSantana\build\web\WEB-INF\inputs.txt

Comment: Did you notice the extra `build` directory in the printed path? It is not present in the path mentioned in your question. Is it a typo?

Comment: ..sorry i get tired: exactly that what i was looking for, thx @DavidLevesque

Comment: you are a genius sir, its printing to the build directory, i was just checking the wrong place. it's working fine thank you very much

Comment: ..consider to accept answer! ..good work, guys! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Did you notice the extra build directory in the printed path? It is not present in the path mentioned in your question.